# preselect type fonts in org-mode with latex and fontenc

Tags: fonts, org-mode

I am looking to assign specific fonts to each type of shape, with the command that I have given it only works for what is between braces, I want, for example, when I put \rmfamily (roman) to be able to write what I want and then put \sffamily and the same sans serifs.

I am using fontenc and pdflatex.
Any ideas?

I have used fontfamily and usepackage, with newcommand I get it but it is not what I am looking for that works only for a text between { }

Fixed, the command I was looking for was:

```
#+latex_header: \usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet} \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{charter}\renewcommand\familydefault{\rmdefault}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code you have tried so far!

Comment: it is very hard to guess your tex question, and impossible to guess how this relates to [tag:org-mode]